# Move div animation onmouseover,onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code below:

JavaScript:

```
function showMenu(){
    var t = setInterval(move, 5);
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    var pos = 0;

    function move(){
        if(pos>=150){
            clearInterval(t);
        }
        else{
            pos += 1;
            menu.style.left = pos + "px";
        }
    }

}

function hideMenu(){
    var t = setInterval(move, 10);
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    var pos = menu.getAttribute("left");

    function move(){
        if(pos<=0){
            clearInterval(t);
        }
        else{
            pos -= 1;
            menu.style.left = pos + "px";
        }
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu-field" onmouseover="showMenu()" onmouseout="hideMenu()" >
    <div id="menu"></div>
</div>
```

I want the div element to move right on mouse over and start moving back to starting position on mouse out. This does the showMenu function even on mouse out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be better accomplished natively with CSS and no JavaScript. This looks like it will accomplish what you're trying to do:

```css
#menu-field {
  background: #eee;
  height: 200px;
  width: 80px;
}

#menu {
  background: #aaa;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

#menu-field:hover #menu {
  transform: translateX(80px);
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-field">
    <div id="menu">Menu</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the way it moves ;)

Comment: @nmnsud CanIUse pegs global IE9 usage at 0.27% (around 1 in 400 people). Is that really a concern today?